# How do I manually remove old release builds from an expired/deleted plan branch in Bamboo?

Tags: bamboo

I use Bamboo regularly as a QA tester to deploy pull requests and feature branches/release branches, but I'm not a developer and have a layman's understanding of how it works.

Our Bamboo configuration is set up to remove inactive branches after a certain amount of time (2 weeks) which happens pretty regularly with longer-term projects, unfortunately. (When that happens, I do know how to configure a new plan and run a new build.) Often, with these larger projects, they've been deployed manually many times over the course of the project, resulting in a large list of possible "release" versions when I go to "Promote existing release to this environment."

Now, I have a brand-new build of a brand-new plan for a project I've been working on off and on for *a year* and I would like to delete all these old builds (releases?) that show up in the dropdown when I want to just deploy the current version of the current new build, but I can't figure out where to do it (neither can the devs I've asked, but it's NBD to them, whereas this is a constant annoyance for me).

All the advice I can find online says things like "all builds are automatically deleted when the branch expires ...." and that doesn't seem to be true, because these are definitely from old expired plan branches. They also explain how to delete things manually .... from an existing plan branch, which I don't have, because the older plan branches expired and were removed.

Am I using the wrong terminology here and these aren't "builds" and there's a separate way to delete them? Do we have a setup that's failing to delete them when it should? Do devs need to do something different with their branches? I obviously don't have access to global settings but I could put in a request if that's what needs to change.

To be clear, I'm talking about going to deployment preview, selecting "promote existing release to this environment," entering in the jira number/beginning of the branch name, and seeing a million of these (which all look identical because our branch names are hella long):

[deployment preview screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYafC.png)

I have read through all the Bamboo documentation relating to plans, builds, branches, and deployment, and Googled various combinations of relevant keywords and haven't found a solution. I've also asked devs I work with and they don't know either.